# My C# code does not run until I click again

Tags: javascript, c#

im calling a JS function inside a c# method in ASP, this is my html:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" CssClass="btns" Text="test confirm delete" OnClick="testDelete"/>
```

and this is the testDelete method:

```
protected void testDelete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 2;
  int res = x + y;
  if (res > 1) {
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "testDel()",true);
    if (hc2.Value == "true") {
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Ok');", true);
      //Here im gonna do a SQL Delete Query
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the JS function

```
function testDel() {
  document.getElementById("hc2").value = confirm("you want to delete?").toString();
  console.log(document.getElementById("hc2").value);
}
```

As you can see in the JS function i am assigning the confirm value to my "hc2" element of the html, and I use that same element in my C# code to check if the user clicked YES or CANCEL, and if the user clicked OK the Alert and the SQL query runs.

the assignment of the confirm value  to "hc2" element  works, but the alert does not work until I click the button again.

Comment: Does `RegisterStartupScript` actually run your test method, or does it just register it?

Comment: it actually runs the test method

Comment: OK.  Didn't know that.  `RegisterStartupScript` seems like an unfortunate choice of naming, if that's what it does.

Comment: So the problem here is that `testDelete` is a server side function that requires a post. On the initial click since the html element hasn't been touched yet, only registers the first startup script. On the second click the server receives the mutated value and registers both startup scripts.  I'd suggest doing this work via ajax calls rather then server posts.

Comment: Yeah, that's my take as well.  You're closing the barn door *after* the horse has bolted.

Comment: This kind of server vs client side confusion is quite common with Web Forms. Do you have a choice in the technology you use? I'd highly recommend avoiding Web Forms. It's a dead technology. I've [even blogged about it](http://masonmcg.com/Blog/entry/stop-using-aspnet-webforms).

Comment: Agreed.  Consider ASP.NET MVC instead of Web Forms.

Comment: if you cant convert to MVC because it's too much, i'd consider doing all of that in javascript and then when the user clicks on YES (i am sure), then from Java Script, call a hidden asp button that does the sql.

Comment: Yes, it's too much, i cant convert to MVC at this stage, im gonna try that @MannySanchez thank you and thank you to everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a bit of JavaScript you can use that replaces the code behind logic. Once you get a confirmation, call the codebehind function via JavaScript.

html:

```
<asp:button id="BtnConfirm" Runat="Server" OnClientClick="testDelete()" /> <br> 
<asp:button id="BtnYes" Runat="Server" OnClick="ASPFunction" visible="false" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function testDelete() {
      var x = 0;
      var y = 2;
      var res = x + y;
      if (res > 1) {
      var rslt = confirm("Do you want to delete?");
      }

    if (rslt == true) {
        document.getElementById("BtnYes").click();

        } else {
      //  block of code to be executed if the condition is false
        }  
    }
```

and CodeBehind:

```
protected void BtnYes(object sender, EventArgs e) {
//sql stuff goes here
}
```